# How to get actual size of mounted SD card in Android?

Tags: android, memory, size, storage, external

I'm trying to find a way to find the total size and free space of a mounted SD card on a phone, from my research on SOF and on the Android devs site I was able to find the method getExternalStorageDirectory() but according to the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) this returns a directory that is not necessarily external:

"Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer."

So I gather from the way that is worded that the "external storage" directory can actually be apart of multiple physical storage devices (internal and external memory). And from my testing that's what I've found as the size that is being returned by using this method is around 1.5x the size of my actual SD card.

So my question is, is there a programmatical way to return the total size and available space just on the SD card? The phone itself can give me that information so I feel like there should be a way but I'm at a loss right now... any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
This is the code I'm currently using for total size

```
private long TotalSDMemory(){
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getAbsolutePath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    long totalSpace = totalBlocks * blockSize;
    Log.d(TAG,"Size of total SD Memory: "+totalSpace);
    Log.d(TAG, "External storage emulated: "+Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated());
    return totalSpace;
}
```

Edit(2):
I didn't know this mattered but I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 which is what I am using to test the code, apparently Samsung has a different file structure for their external memory. Here is a link that should help anyone else get the correct size:
[Get size of SD card in Samsung phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087510/check-if-the-sdcard-is-present-boolean-is-always-true)

Comment: Edit(2): I didn't know this mattered but I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 which is what I am using to test the code, apparently Samsung has a different file structure for their external memory. Here is a link that should help anyone else get the correct size: [Getsize of SD card in Samsung phones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087510/check-if-the-sdcard-is-present-boolean-is-always-true)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long sdAvailSize = (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks()
               * (long)stat.getBlockSize();
//One binary gigabyte equals 1,073,741,824 bytes.
long gigaAvailable = sdAvailSize / 1073741824;
```

Got that from here: [How can I check how much free space an SD card mounted on an Android device has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941552/android-sd-card-free-space)

Concerning your question about getting total size look here: [Getting all the total and available space on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799643/getting-all-the-total-and-available-space-on-android)

---

***Edit:***

**[Marcelo Filho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575643/marcelo-filho%20%22Marcelo%20Filho) has pointed out that this method is deprecated in API 18 (KitKat).**

[Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html#getAvailableBlocks%28%29) suggests to use `getAvailableBlocksLong ()` and `getBlockCountLong ()` instead. Both methods will return a **long** value and **not** a double.

***Hint:***

[Kikiwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898596/kikiwa) has pointed out that the datatype *long* should be used with these -now deprecated - methods, otherwise you may get negative values if the filesize is too large.

Comment: If you're using getAvailableBlocks() or getBlocks() (deprecated API), always cast the value in long as soon as possible (for values greater than 3GB, the int will be negative!).

Comment: @Peter do you mean with "mounted sdcard" the internal storage? There might be a conflict in this name calling, since the OP was asking for the external storage.

Comment: @DuKes0mE i was tested on two phones. 2.3.4  and 4.4.  On 4.4  - it's show like 1.5 gb full.  On 2.3.4 it's showing mounted card  5-32 gb  :( cant find correct way to fix it

Comment: @Peter I am asking again: do you mean the external storage of the mounted sd card (like the opening post was asking for) or the internal storage? If you look for internal, did you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8133437/2245646

Comment: This shouldn't be accepted. getExternalStorageDirectory returns the internal storage. Not the storage from removable sd card

Comment: @MSeiz5, getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated as you can see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 2):

```
public String[] getSize() throws IOException {
    String memory="";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df /mnt/sdcard");
    InputStream is =p.getInputStream();
    int by=-1;
    while((by=is.read())!=-1) {
        memory+=new String(new byte[]{(byte)by});
    }
    for (String df:memory.split("/n")) {
        if(df.startsWith("/mnt/sdcard")) {
            String[] par = df.split(" ");
            List<String> pp=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String pa:par) {
                if(!pa.isEmpty()) {
                    pp.add(pa);
                }
            }
            return pp.toArray(new String[pp.size()]);

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

getSize()[0] is /mnt/sdcard. getSize()[1] is size of sd (example 12.0G), getSize()[2] is used, [3] is free, [4] is blksize

Or:

```
new File("/sdcard/").getFreeSpace() - bytes of free in long
new File("/sdcard/").getTotalSpace() - size of sd
```