# How to get TOTAL memory and internal storage size Android?

Tags: java, android, size, storage, ram

I'm attempting to get the total memory (RAM) and internal storage size, but every method I have used is reporting it too low. I'm aware the kernel may take up some of it but I need to know how much there is installed in total.

For the memory I first just read from /proc/meminfo/ then used the `getMemoryInfo`. Each of these reported less than the amount of memory installed (700MB instead of 1GB).

for the internal storage size I am using `Environment.getDataDirectory`, `getBlockSizeLong` and `getBlockCountLong`. The result of this is much lower than the amount of storage I know is installed. The settings in the OS agree with the amount reported by my method but I need to know the total amount installed not just what it thinks is there (Even as I typed that it sounded counter-intuitive in my head).

Edit: I've looked at the questions that are being sent and tried their methods as I said. The values reported are incorrect compared for what I know is installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get total RAM size of a device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374246/how-to-get-total-ram-size-of-a-device) AND [Getting all the total and available space on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799643/getting-all-the-total-and-available-space-on-android) Searching the site before asking a question is really helpful to you and the community

Comment: As I said in the question I have tried the methods mentioned in those threads. Those methods are reporting values lower than needed.

Comment: Post the values you're getting from these methods. What value do you get from `memInfo.totalMem`?

Comment: memInfo.totalMem gives a value of 879MB when the value is set to to 1024MB on the emulator.

Comment: Such behavior is normal on avds, try the code on a real device and you'll see that it's reporting the correct amount of RAM.

Answer (score 5):

for RAM:

[Total RAM available android APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android)

Basically is:

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
```

Storage:

[Available STORAGE Android APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card)

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getBlockCount();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Duplicate questions are better forwarded to their duplicate threads rather than answering them, in my opinion.

Comment: As I said I've tried using `getMemoryInfo` it reports 700KB instead of 1GB. as for storage I need the **Internal** storage space.

Comment: @prettyvoid I agree but those are two previous answers combined. Thanks