# Getting Device RAM and Internal Storage in GB

Tags: android, memory, ram, internal-storage

I need to get the app ram and internal storage in GB (Gigabytes).

I tried this

```
private void getAppRam() {

        String DeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
        String DeviceName = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String sdk = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

        System.out.println("DeviceModel...." + DeviceModel);
        System.out.println("DeviceName ...." + DeviceName);
        System.out.println("sdk ...." + sdk);

        ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
        long totalMemory = memInfo.totalMem / (1024 * 1024);
        System.out.println("ram...." + totalMemory);
    }
```

But did not found accurate results, and can someone suggest any solution for internal storage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all the total and available space on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799643/getting-all-the-total-and-available-space-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this

For getting Total RAM:

```
private long totalRamMemorySize() {
  ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
  long availableMegs = mi.totalMem / 1048576L;
  return availableMegs;
 }
```

For Getting Total Internal Menory:

```
public static long getTotalInternalMemorySize() {
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    return totalBlocks * blockSize;
 }
```

For more data, Try this Link [Get Device RAM and Internal Storage - Induces Smile](https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-get-android-ram-internal-and-external-memory-information/)